# Взять из строки слова которые начинаются с большой буквы

Tags: c#, linq

Есть текст, из которого надо взять слова начинающиеся с большой буквы.

```
решИла нЕ Упрощать и зашифРОВАтЬ Все послаНИЕ
дАже не Старайся нИЧЕГО у тЕбя нЕ получится с расшифРОВкой
Сдавайся НЕ твоего ума Ты не споСОбЕн Но может быть
если особенно упорно подойдешь к делу

будет Трудно конечнО
Код ведЬ не из простых
очень ХОРОШИЙ код
то у тебя все получится
и я буДу Писать тЕбЕ еще

чао
```

мой код

```
data.Split(' ').Select(x => x).Where(x=>char.IsUpper(x[0])).Reverse().ToList();
```

Почему то он не берет все слова которые начинаются с большой буквы. Мой результат

```
Писать ХОРОШИЙ Трудно Но Ты НЕ Старайся Все Упрощать
```

А должно получиться

```
Писать ХОРОШИЙ Код Трудно Но Ты НЕ Сдавайся Старайся Все Упрощать
```

Что в моем коде не так*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что вы делите по пробелу, а нужно включить в разделяющие символы ещё и конец строки (и Tab, наверное).

Ещё одна потенциальная проблема: Вы берёте первый символ слова, не проверив длину слова.

Ну и конструкция `Select(x => x)` не изменяет последовательность и таким образом не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Можно решить проблему поиска разделителей, табов, переносов строк и прочих запятых через регулярные выражения:

```
string pattern = @"\b\p{Lu}.*?\b";

var words = Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Reverse();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", words));
```

- `\b` - граница слова
- `\p{Lu}` - большая буква
- `.*?` - любые символы, но как можно меньше (т.е. очередное `\b` совпадет с ближайшей границей слова)

Answer (score 1):

```
 data.Split(' ', '\n')
.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
.Where(x => char.IsUpper(x[0]))
.Reverse();
```

Добавил в разделители перенос строки и проверку на то, что строка не пустая, как советовал VladD, теперь работает правильно.

Comment: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`